# Using 'POST' in PHP to retrieve database information via JSON in C#

Tags: c#, php, json, mysqli, xamarin

Been breaking my brain on this all day and am at my whits end. I have a c# cross platform mobile application.  I need to retrieve information from a mysql db on my server as JSON.  No matter what i try (and believe me i've rewritten the php and c# about 20 times each with many methods sourced from google nothing is working).

I basically need to POST an id, and receive the result of a query via JSON.

Something along the lines of:

PHP:

```
<?php
function getStatusCodeMessage($status)
{
$codes = parse_ini_file("codes.ini");

return (isset($codes[$status])) ? $codes[$status] : '';
}

function sendResponse($status = 200, $body = '', $content_type = 'application/json') 
{
$status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . getStatusCodeMessage($status);
header($status_header);
header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);
echo $body;
}

class myClass 
{

private $db;

function __construct() 
{
$this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$this->db->autocommit(FALSE);
}

function __destruct() 
{
$this->db->close();
}

function processRequest() 
{
if (isset($_POST["id"])) {
$id = $_POST["id"];

try {
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT 1, 2, 3, 4 FROM table WHERE id=?');
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$result = $stmt->execute();
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
return false;
}

if($result){
$content = $stmt->fetchAll();
}

sendResponse(200, json_encode($content));
return true;
}

sendResponse(400, 'Invalid request');
return false;
}
}

$example = new myClass;
$example->processRequest();

?>
```

Then in c# i need something like:

```
public string GetInfo(int id)
{
    string url = Globals.URL + "/GetInfo";
    string postData = "id=" + id;
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);


    WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
    myRequest.Method = "POST";
    myRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    myRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

    try
    {
        Stream stream1 = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
        stream1.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        stream1.Close();
        WebResponse response = myRequest.GetResponse();
        if (response == null)
            return null;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        output = "Something went wrong.";
    }

    if (result != null)
    {
        doSomethingWithJson(result);
        output = "Success!";
    }
    else
    {
        output = "Something went wrong.";
    }
    return output;
}
```

Please keep in mind i just wrote this code in the stack overflow postbox so it isnt perfect.

What am i doing wrong?   How do i get a JSON response?  Currently all i can get is a 400 bad request or 500 server error.

Thanks

EDIT:

I found this issue was in using execute(); rather than query();.  Whilst execute works fine for echo's etc it seems you cannot return a result via httprequest using it.  I also found php was casting the ID as a string so i had to force it to use int.

Something along the lines of;

```
    if (isset($_POST["id"])) {
        $id = (int)$_POST["id"];

        $stmt = "SELECT 1,2,3,4 FROM table WHERE id = $id";

        try {
            foreach ($this->db->query($stmt) as $row) {
            $rows[] = $row;
            }
        } catch(PDOException $ex) {
            return false;
        }

        sendResponse(200, json_encode($rows));
        return true;
        }
```

If you go with this solution keep in mind by not 'preparing' the SQL statement you leave yourself vulnerable to injection so be sure to do something about that ;)

Comment: To start with, does your PHP code work?  Have you tested it using POSTMAN or some similar tool?  Focus on getting the server side working, then the client code should be simple.

Comment: It doesnt work through postman.   So where do i go from here.

Comment: That should tell you something is wrong with your server side code.  Debug it.  Start from square 1 - does your db connection work?  Can you do a simple select?  Can you return a hardcoded json response?  Verify each piece and then start to put them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to show the way of doing this using C#
in your web page lets say there is button and text box in your web form called pageName.aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<input type="button" value="Get" onclick="GetJSONData()" />
```

then add script tag at the bottom of body tag. Also add json and jquery reffernces correctly

```
<script src="../js/jquery.1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function GetJSONData() {
       var id = $('#txtID').val();
       $.ajax({
           url: "pageName.aspx/GetData",   // Current Page, Method
           data: JSON.stringify({ id: id }), // parameter map as JSON  
           type: "POST", // data has to be POSTed  
           contentType: "application/json", // posting JSON content      
           dataType: "JSON",  // type of data is JSON (must be upper case!)  
           timeout: 10000,    // AJAX timeout  
           success: function(result) {
                   alert(result.d);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status) {
               alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
           }
       });
   }
```

then in code behind(pageName.aspx.cs) file add following method.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetData(string id)
    {
        string retData=string.Empty;
        //do whatever you want...
        //and assign result to retData
        return retData;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately can't use asp.net as this is being built onto a large software thats running on linux.   Great solution though!

Answer (score 0):

You are sending `$result` back which will be a boolean. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) . What you have to do is to send the `$content` as json array.

Comment: My live copy has $content, stuffed this up when writing this post up.

Comment: The url to the php file in your c# code is it right? Try putting that url in browser directly with an echo on top of your php file to check

Comment: Link is correct in vis studio however it seems the php doesnt work in POSTMAN.